# John Wick Chapter 2/3 discrepancy

Tags: john-wick-chapter-2, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum, production-mistakes

At the end of John Wick 2, when Winston tells John he has one hour until he goes excommunicado, his watch reads 3:58pm. In Chapter 3, John goes excommunicado at precisely 6pm.  Was this just an error?

[image: John Wick 2 Winston's watch]

Comment: Has he moved to a different city with different timezones between these two events?

Comment: No, they're basically the same event.

Answer (score 3):

This part is listed as a continuity goof in [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6146586/goofs):

> At the end of John Wick 2 when Winston gives the excomunicado order its 4 pm on his watch and he says John Wick has 1 hour.But in Part 3 he becomes excomunicado effective 6 pm which should have been 5 pm according to the ending in Part 2

and there is this video about some errors in John Wick, the error you mention is at 12:55.